# How to get $_GET URL (sometimes it makes an array with multiple elements)

Tags: php, get

I've just start to learn some php, and I'm trying to make a simple php script. All it will do is ask a person for a link, and then it will convert it in a hyper link.

---

***How people can use my website:***

**The first way is they can**

1. Go to `localhost/link-to-hyperlink.php`
2. Put in the url in my form. Like: `https://google.com`
3. Then my php script converts it into a hyper link.

**Second way they can is they can:**

1. `Go to localhost/link-to-hyperlink.php?url=https://google.com`
2. Then my php script converts it into a hyper link.

---

***My Problem***

Both my things work, but when someone submits a url like this `https://google.com/something.php?name=bob&age=12&fav-nums=200;300;400` my program doesn't work properly. It makes the hyper link `https://google.com/something.php?name=bob`, not the entire URL.

Also happens on partially encoded urls like: `localhost/link-to-hyperlink.php?url=https://google.com?something.php?names=bob%3Bmike%3Bsam&age=30%3B23%3B22&fav-nums=200%3B300%3B400`.

It only happens when someone decides to use the second way to convert the link. I printed the $_GET array and you can see that it makes multiple indexes in the $_GET. I would like to facilitate their mis-use.

The array look liks this:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://google.com/something.php?name=bob
    [age] => 12
    [fav-nums] => 200;300;400
)
```

---

My program: `link-to-hyperlink.php`

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['url']) == false) {
        $answer = "Enter a URL<br>";
    } else {
        $answer = '<a target="_blank" href="' . $_GET['url'] . '">Your Hyperlink</a><br>';
    }

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Link To Hyerplink Converter</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>
The array structure was:

<?php print_r($_GET); ?>
    </pre>
    <br>
    <?php echo $answer; ?>
    <form action="link-to-hyperlink.php" method="GET">
        Your URL:<br>
        <input type="text" name="url"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please attach the actual output of `print_r`?

Comment: @TheNavigat Done (added to first post)

Comment: Are you sure it only happens the first way and not only the second way?

Comment: If someone goes to `localhost/link-to-hyperlink.php?url=https://google.com?name=bob&age=5` they're using your service incorrectly. They need to urlencode individual query string parameters

Comment: They should be going to `localhost/link-to-hyperlink.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%3Fname%3Dbob%26age%3D5`.

Comment: @Paulpro Sorry, I mean the second way only. It only happens the second. My bad. If they are using it incorrectly, I would still like to facilitate their mistake and still make it work. If there an efficient way i can facilitate their mistake.

Comment: You could detect if `count($_GET) > 1` and then give them a message telling them they should encode the url parameter. You could even recommend the correct url, or you could try to just make it work anyway; but I personally think that is a bad idea.

Comment: @Paulpro But I would like to facilitate their mistake, rather than telling then throwing an error. How can I facilitate the mistake and still give them the hyper link they wanted

Comment: That is not a good idea. You will not be able to handle all cases (in particular the cases where their url contains a `#` or another `url` parameter in its own query string). In general it is never a good idea to try to correct user errors, and instead to tell them where they went wrong. Trying to make things work despite being used incorrectly is why there are so many inconsistencies between web browsers.

Comment: Design an interface and throw an error when your service is used in an invalid way. An error describing the correct way to use it is much better than having it randomly work sometimes and then randomly fail for certain urls (IE. any with a `#` in them), especially if your spec says that it works that way.

Comment: Also, of course it is an error if the `url` query string parameter is only partially url encoded. Query string parameters need to be completely url encoded all the time.

Comment: That all said, you can probably copy the `$_GET` array into a new array and remove 'url' from it e.g. `$extra_args = $_GET; unset( $extra_args[ 'url' ] );` and then do something like `$url = $_GET['url'] . (count( $extra_args ) > 1 ? '&' . http_build_query( $extra_args ) : '')`. I highly recommend not to do that and to always avoiding trying to fix users mistakes and instead inform them that they made one. That's better for your users too.